# bosting functionality of a most basic fingerprint reader

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics

I have developed an online school management system. Now my client wants to implement fingerprint verification. What he wants is to store some biometric data for each student; this data is then compared to data of person swiping the finger and his personal data comes up...

I found this cheap Athena A101 http://www.biometrics.com.my/fingerprint-reader.html

The thing is there is no SDK, just some driver. And it is limited to 10 fingerprints. What I don't understand is once it is able to compare and store 10 fingerprints why not a 100 or 1000? I'm guessing this data is stored on the device itself. Why not store it on hdd?

Anyway my question: is there any way of cracking this? Has anybody done this before? Obviously the hardware is there, has anybody ever written software that is able to get data from these cheap devices and store them somewhere? You know making this device much more useful. Thank you for your help chaps.

Comment: Because comparing a fingerprint to 10 others (like you might with a laptop having multiple owners) is a very different problem than comparing that same fingerprint to a database of a thousand fingerprints.  The latter problem is *much* harder (and substantially more expensive, involving more sophisticated software and fingerprint readers with higher precision).

Comment: A fingerprint recognition system can be used for 
both verification and identification. In *verification*, the 
system compares an input fingerprint to the “enrolled” 
fingerprint of a specific user to determine if they are 
from the same finger (1:1 match). In *identification*, the 
system compares an input fingerprint with the prints 
of all enrolled users in the database to determine if the 
person is already known under a duplicate or false identity (1:N match)

Comment: For your school application, it is likely that you will need an "identification" type system, not a verification one.  http://biometrics.cse.msu.edu/Publications/Fingerprint/JainFpMatching_IEEEComp10.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wish to investigate the [`libpam-fprint`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libpam-fprint) module: it integrates `libfprint` with PAM in a manner that allows fingerprint mechanisms to be used for authentication with any service that integrates with PAM.

This would make changing authentication mechanisms in the future easy enough -- drop in a new PAM module -- and gives you independence from any specific vendor's toolkits.